# vbscripting object doesn't support property or method If elseif else

Tags: vbscript

so I'm pretty new to coding, especially in Vbscript, so I've been messing around, trying to learn by doing. So I've been working on a little program that will take the username (like the computer username), add up the letters, and insult the user based on the sum, because why not. I keep running into an error on **line 10** though, and because of the way my code is set up, I'm pretty sure I'll run into it on every subsequent line as well. Can you please help me? I keep getting error code **800A01B6 "Object doesn't support this property or method."**
(I deleted the insults because of the language used, don't worry about that...)

```
Dim networkInfo
Dim nameVal
Dim infoStr
Dim insult

Set networkInfo = CreateObject("WScript.NetWork") 
nameVal=1
infoStr = networkInfo.UserName & vbCr & vbLf

if InStr(1, networkInfo, "a") > 0 Then
    nameVal = nameVal + 1
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "b") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 2
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "c") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 3
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "d") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 4
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "e") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 5
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "f") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 6
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "g") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 7
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "h") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 8
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "i") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 9
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "j") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 10
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "k") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 11
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "l") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 12
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "m") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 13
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "n") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 14
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "o") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 15
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "p") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 16
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "q") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 17
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "r") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 18
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "s") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 19
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "t") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 20
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "u") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 21
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "v") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 22
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "w") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 23
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "x") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 24
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "y") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 25
Elseif      InStr(1, networkInfo, "z") > 0 Then
                nameVal = nameVal + 26  
Else        MsgBox ("") 

End If

If nameVal < 5 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 5 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 10 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 20 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 30 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 40 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 50 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 60 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 70 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 80 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 90 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 100 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 110 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 120 Then
    insult = ("")
Elseif nameVal  > 130 Then
    insult = (".")
Elseif nameVal  > 140 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 150 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 160 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 170 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 180 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 190 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 200 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 210 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 220 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 230 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 240 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 250 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 260 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 270 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 280 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 290 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 300 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 310 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 320 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 330 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 340 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 350 Then
    insult = (".")  
Elseif nameVal  > 360 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 370 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 380 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 390 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 400 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 410 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 420 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal = 420 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 430 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 440 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 450 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 460 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 470 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 480 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 490 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 500 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 510 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 520 Then
    insult = ("")   
Elseif nameVal  > 530 Then
    insult = ("")   
End If      
MsgBox infoStr & insult
```

If you can also give me tips on how to make this code more efficient or better structured, I would appreciate that as well! Thank you for taking the time to read this and any help you may give me.

Comment: This is a classic case of breaking a prime principle of programming - [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). What is it you are trying to do? You could use an `Array` for each value and use a loop to run through them and perform the check without all those repeated lines, hard to read, inefficient and a pain to manage.

Comment: I don't think your script is working how you want it to at the moment. It looks like you want to check for all the letter variations in the username and generate a numeric value from it, however, at the moment it will only check for the first match so your next check for example for `Elseif nameVal = 420 Then` will never be hit the largest number the first check will produce is `26`.

Answer (score 2):

**`InStr`** works only with **`String`** and in your code you are using it with **`Object`**, hence getting error. Replace your line:

```
if InStr(1, networkInfo, "a") > 0 Then
```

With:

```
if InStr(1, infoStr, "a") > 0 Then
```

Also use [**`Select...Case`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) instead of bunch of **`If and ElseIf`**.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

[@manishchristian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652222/manishchristian) has [answered the initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637798/692942).

However, judging by the code you are trying to generate a numeric value based on a User Name. At the moment the code you have written will not work as you expect because you have no code to loop through and check all the conditions.

The code is also very repetitive and cumbersome which breaks a key principle in programming, [DRY *(Don't Repeat Yourself)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Below is just one of many ways you could tackle this problem. the method uses a nested Array to set the character and numeric value associated to it *(easily configurable, by changing the values)*. It then loops through each character in the User Name and applies the logic in one line instead of unwieldy `If` statement.

***Side Note:*** If the `letters` Array always follows the same pattern there is nothing to stop you building that dynamically which is even less code.

```
Option Explicit
Dim i, nameVal
Dim netinfo: Set netinfo = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
Dim username: username = netinfo.UserName

Dim letter
Dim letters: letters = Array( _
      Array("a", 1), Array("b", 2), Array("c", 3), Array("d", 4), Array("e", 5) _
    , Array("f", 6), Array("g", 7), Array("h", 8), Array("i", 9), Array("j", 10) _
    , Array("k", 11), Array("l", 12), Array("m", 13), Array("n", 14), Array("o", 15) _
    , Array("p", 16), Array("q", 17), Array("r", 18), Array("s", 19), Array("t", 20) _
    , Array("u", 21), Array("v", 22), Array("w", 23), Array("x", 24), Array("y", 25) _
    , Array("z", 26))

For i = 1 To Len(username)
    For Each letter In letters
        If LCase(Mid(username, i, 1)) = LCase(letter(0)) Then nameVal = nameVal + letter(1)
    Next
Next

WScript.Echo username & " = " & nameVal
```

Output:

```
Joe.Bloggs = 92
```